# Restart rsyslog from within the Apache Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd, dbus, systemctl

I have Apache Docker container and rsyslog installed on it as `apt install rsyslog`.The problem is that when I run docker container and then wish to `systemctl restart rsyslog`, then it fails with

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: WARNING: No init system and policy-rc.d missing! Defaulting to block.
```

The weirdest part is that just with the same configuration (docker-compose) I'am able to do that from within Gitlab CI/CD.

Is it kinda Gitlab magic, or what I have to do to perform such an operation on my local computer as well?

UPD: I do run a container with `--priveleged` and `--volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro`

Comment: A Docker container runs only a single process, and containers rarely run the heavyweight systemd init system.  Do you need to run the second process in a second container?  Or are you trying to restart syslogd on the host?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need to run 2 processes (apache and rsyslog) inside a container AND at any point of time being able to `systemctl restart rsyslog` inside a container (just like it is done on a host (you bring down a service then you can bring it up and it works)

Comment: To reiterate, a Docker container is a wrapper around a _process_; it is not a host, and `systemctl` doesn't work in it.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it doesn't, but how then Gitlab CI/CD with the same docker-compose could actually run `systemctl restart rsyslog` inside a container?